# How do I restore an Azure database

Tags: azure

Azure is Killing Me, I have just accidently cleared out my database (client database), damn it I hate code first migrations.

I have searched through videos and messages for a way to restore my database and the option is not available.

This video says that restore is available on all tiers (at 20 second mark).

http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Windows-Azure/Restore-a-SQL-Database-Using-Point-in-Time-Restore

This message is in my portal

[image]

The help says it should be available in the command bar, but it's not there

[image]

Looks like I'm totally screwed by SQL Azure, even though there is plent of writing and videos to say that all databases are backed up on all plans, that seems to be crap.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure where you are reading that Point in Time restore is available on all tiers; The tiers that it is supported on are clearly listed.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj650016.aspx.  "If you have Web or Business Edition databases, you must create your own backup strategy."

Comment: however, honestly, if you are using a Web or Business database, you should already be considering migration, since those tiers will be retired in September, 2015.

Comment: it even says `Web(retired)` in your database edition on your Management panel.

Comment: The top picture shows a message quite boldly saying that I have backups, this message is crap

Comment: Most people ask questions. You posted a rant. Looking past that: Are you using web/business edition? Or basic/standard/premium edition? Oh wait - others have asked the same question. Web/Business editions don't have point in time backup/restore (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj650016.aspx)). Oh - another edit for me: From your screenshot, you're using Web (as @Claies pointed out). No backup/restore on that tier (a retired tier).

Answer (score 2):

SQL Azure backup information are shown in the servers tab not database.

Navigate to SQL Database >> Servers Tab >> Select your server >> Backups Tab.

If you have any backups it will show in this place.

You can also use powershell to get a list of restore points:

```
PS C:\> Get-AzureSqlRecoverableDatabase -ServerName xxxxxxxxxx

Name      Edition      ServerName      LastAvailableBackupDate
----      -------      ----------      -----------------------
logs      Basic        xxxxxxxxxx      18/05/2015 16:15:14
tracker   Basic        xxxxxxxxxx      17/05/2015 14:31:49
events    Basic        xxxxxxxxxx      17/05/2015 15:02:23
```

Said that:

- ***Restore*** button should also appear in the dashboard bottom action bar if you have any backups for the selected database.
- Automatic Backups were and are still not available on retired **web** or **business** tiers.